# Thread without access to WordPress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, pthreads

An Admin or Editor can send out emails to users via our WordPress Plugin customised to the individual so the emails are sent individually, this can make the page wait a while for the mailing process to finish. The plan is to multithreaded to return the user to the page and let the emails carry on sending on the server. The problem seems to be lack of access to WordPress' wp_mail() function from the thread's run() function. Calling wp-load.php does not seem to give access to WordPress functions.

Below is a simplified version of the threaded mailer. How do we use the wp-mail() function from the Test_Mailer thread?

```
class Test_Mailer extends Thread {
    private $email;

    public function __construct($emails, $subject, $message) {
        $this->emails = $emails;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function run() {
        require( '../../../wp-load.php' );

        foreach($this->emails as $email)
            wp_mail( $email, $this->subject, $this->message);
    }
}

$test_mailer = new test_mailer(array('test@test.com'), 'Subject', 'Message');
$test_mailer->start();
```

EDIT: If I try accessing a WordPress function nothing happens as shown below, which makes me think that WP is not loaded, but I do not get any errors in the PHP error log.

```
class Test_Thread extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        update_option('test', 'two');
    }
}

update_option('test', 'one');
$test_thread = new test_mailer();
$test_thread->start();
// test option is set to 'one'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new thread, pthreads will make a copy of all functions (as well as classes, interfaces, traits, etc) available from the current environment (unless selective inheritance flags have been used in `Thread::start`, of course). This means that if you have already included the `wp-load.php` file, then you do not need to include it again inside of the new thread (in `Thread::run`). (If you haven't included this file yet, then what you've done is fine.)

Looking at your example code, you are assigning the `$emails` parameter from the constructor to the `$this->emails` property. However, the `foreach` is attempting to iterate over the `$this->email_array` property, which will simply be `null`. So from your example code at least, it looks like the problem is with what property you're accessing, rather than the `wp_mail` function not being accessible.

With all that said, it does look like you're attempting to use pthreads in a web server environment. This has its own ramifications and is simply a bad idea. You'd be better off queueing such tasks (via RabbitMQ or something) to handle them elsewhere.

**UPDATE (from your update):**

Having a brief look through the WordPress codebase, I can see that threading simply isn't going to work here. The codebase is just incredibly unfriendly to such concurrency techniques.

The `update_option` function will not work because it relies upon a global DB connection. This connection cannot be used across different contexts (threads) - instead, a new connection must be created per thread.

The `wp_mail` function uses the `get_bloginfo` function, which in turn uses the `get_option` function, which in turn has a global for DB access. So you're going to have the same problem there as above.

Given the ubiquity of globals in the WordPress codebase, threading is simply not going to work here...

Comment: The $email_array thing was a typo on my part, I simplified the code to post on here. When running the thread WordPress is already loaded but the thread is unable to call WP functions, I've added an edit with a test thread I've just tried, it calls update_option in the thread which does not make the change it is supposed to. When removing the first update_option the value remains unchanged in the DB. I figured the problem was that the thread could not see the WP functions as in its little thread WP was not loaded, perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @PeterBushnell I've updated my answer based upon your update.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm keen to use wp_mail as has been filtered to add unsubscribe links to every email. I'll go with a more conventional solution like AJAX and update the page to show the admin that work is in progress and not to leave the page.

Answer (score 1):

You're loading WordPress all over again with that `require( '../../../wp-load.php' );`. That's what [Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) is for.

The meat of the following example are the actions `wp_ajax_` (logged users) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` (non logged users). These are the PHP actions to execute by a JavaScript call, in your case `wp_mail()`.

You have to enqueue the JS file in the correct page and pass some variables via `wp_localize_script` (Ajax URL, security nonce, custom stuff).

It creates an admin page with a link that prompts for an email. The address is passed to the Ajax function that sends the email and returns `true` or `false` depending on `wp_mail()` result.

## Example plugin:

```
<?php
/** 
  * Plugin Name: (B5F) Test Email
  * Version: 1.0
  * Author: brasofilo
  */

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_43678305');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mail_43678305', 'mail_43678305' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mail_43678305', 'mail_43678305' );

function add_menu_43678305() {
    $page = add_menu_page( 
        'sendMail', 
        '<span style="color:#d00;">Send Mail</span>', 
        'read', 
        'send-mail', 
        'menu_page_43678305', 
        'http://i.imgur.com/Vk42k.png', 
        6 // position, just after Posts
    );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$page", 'enqueue_scripts_43678305' );
}

function enqueue_scripts_43678305(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'ajax_script', 
        plugins_url('/ajax_43678305.js',__FILE__), 
        array('jquery'), 
        TRUE 
    );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'ajax_script', 
        'myAjax', 
        array(
            'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "nonce_43678305" ),
        )
    );
}

function menu_page_43678305() {
    echo '<h4><a href="#" id="send-mail">TEST AJAX</a></h4>';
}
function mail_43678305(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'nonce_43678305', 'nonce' );

    if( true ) { // Dummy test
        $sent = wp_mail( $_POST['email'], "Subject", "message" );
        wp_send_json_success( $sent );
    }
    else
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'error' => $custom_error ) );
}
```

## JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#send-mail').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = window.prompt('Email?');
        if ( email === '' || email === null )
            return;

        var data = {
            action: 'mail_43678305', // Ajax PHP function
            nonce: myAjax.nonce, // security, passed via wp_localize_script
            email: email
        };

        $.post( myAjax.url, data, function( response ) {
            $('#send-mail').html( response.data );
        });
    });
});
```